# Using UIKit can you wrap a uiimage?

Tags: uikit, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a game running on the iPhone 3 at 30 fps. I have subclassed UIView to create a scrolling background class. Is it possible to transform a uiimage to create the scrolling effect (wrap the image) or should I be looking at having 4 images and moving the off screen images ready to reappear on the other sides.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're looking for a UIKit solution then take a look at [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). It has zooming and scrolling capabilities and both can be achieve manually (user interaction) and programatically. If this background is very large you should also consider tiling it (ie. dividing it to smaller sections).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to get a parallax scrolling effect. The background image will be a little bigger than the visible screen. I need fine control of the scrolling in 360. I have seen a few posts saying UIScrollView is not very good for this. I am looking to see if I can use a CALayer and shift the image (if it goes off one side it come back on the other). If this is not possible  I'm thinking 4 tiled CALayers may be the way to go.

Comment: By scrolling you also mean rotating? If so, then CALayer would be a better approach for sure.

Comment: Sorry, Not rotating by 360, I meant scrolling up and to the right at the same time.

Comment: I see. Then UIScrollView could also work, you'd just have tweak it's setContentOffset. But if you can handle CALayer you will be better off that way.